# Save android profiler traces of cpu, memory and energy to file all under single session

Tags: android, android-studio, android-profiler

I am using latest version of android studio (electric eel, 2022.1.1 Patch 1). I am checking performance of my android app. I have started a profiling session and I see that I cannot save to disk the trace files of cpu, memory and energy all at the same time. Under a session I can either save cpu or memory. There is no option to save energy data. Could give me pointers to save all the three metrics to disk under same session?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but Android Studio as of today doesn't have the capability to do so. It may be a good idea to file a feature request to the team, using this [link](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=192708&template=840533). You can change the Type from "Bug" to "Feature Request" in the form.